# Native WordPress gallery not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery

I have a Page that requires a Lightbox style Gallery. I am trying to use the native WordPress gallery (via the Media picker).

I can create, add images to and update the Page to include the Shortcode ([gallery link="none" ids="80,81,82"])

However when I update the Page, the thumbnail images are rendered correctly (I assume) but I cannot click on any of the to implement the Lightbox style functionality. I have deactivated all the Plugins I was using. Still nothing.

The page is here: http://keen.devboxlab.co.uk/gallery/

Any help would be much appreciated! WP is version 3.7.1

Thanks,

Kev

Comment: I did not use WP gallery, but installed some plugins: http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-zoom/ and http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/, that worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the jetpack plugin and use its gallery modules.